# How can I achieve single-reader semantics in Cassandra?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, locking, cassandra, distributed

### Goal

I have a table of one-time-use tokens; at most one thread should be able to read any given row. It is acceptable if there is a low chance of a race condition resulting in a row not being readable at all.

### Why

I'm implementing the authorization code flow in OAuth2. The server creates an "auth code" grant token with a unique ID and hands it to the client; the client shortly comes back and tries to redeem the auth code for a real access token. This redemption must happen at most once; if an attacker gets ahold of the auth code, but the client redeems it first, the attacker must not be able to redeem it as well.

The auth codes expire after at most 10 minutes; I store an expiration timestamp column to check on redemption but I'm also using Cassandra's TTL feature (column expiration) for garbage collection.

All operations here are performed with LOCAL_QUORUM. Each auth code is represented by a row with a key equal to the auth code value.

### Unsatisfying/broken solutions

- **Counter column**

  - Maintain a counter column for auth code redemptions. When a thread attempts to redeem an authcode, it first increments the auth code's row in the counter column, then reads the columns for the auth code. If the count is greater than 1, reject. In race conditions, both threads may reject.
  - Validity: I believe this will behave correctly with only all-fail errors.
  - Downside: Cassandra [does not support TTLs](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2103) for counter columns, meaning I would have to run a reaper process.
- Dibs

  - Maintain a string column called "dibs". When a thread attempts to redeem an auth code, it writes a unique ID to the dibs column, then reads the columns. If the dibs value no longer matches, reject.
  - Validity: Nope. Thread 1 writes, reads, accepts. Thread 2 writes, reads, accepts. This is not fixable by merely adding a delete or second write after the read, since that may happen after the other thread's actions.

### Possible solutions

[Lamport's bakery algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_bakery_algorithm) looks suspiciously appropriate but is probably overkill.

### Question

Am I stuck with counter columns for cooperative single-reader locking?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but is hopefully useful information.

Cassandra 2.0 will support compare-and-swap - a server-side implementation of your "dibs" approach that should ensure consistency. From the release notes, this feature is supported in thrift in Cassandra 2.0 and in CQL for 2.0.1.

Depending on your time scale and willingness to potentially use a x.0 release this could be a solution.